# Load SWF from embedded file in Flash

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, loader

Usually we load external swf file into Flash using 'Loader' class.

```
var loader:Loader = new Loader();
loader.load(new URLRequest("http://domain/path/my-external-swf.swf"));
```

However, the external swf file is now embedded in my flash document:

```
[Embed("my-external-swf.swf")]
public var component:Class;
```

Is it possible to tell 'Loader' to load from embedded content instead?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to simply do this:

```
addChild(new component());
```

Hopefully the name `component` won't collide with any reserved variables.

If you still would like to use the [Loader](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/display/Loader.html?filter_flash=cs5&filter_flashplayer=10.2&filter_air=2.6) class, as @Lukasz advises, use the [loadBytes()](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/display/Loader.html#loadBytes%28%29) method and pass the embedded asset. If your swf also contains code, you might need to initialize the [LoaderContext](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/system/LoaderContext.html):

```
var ctx:LoaderContext = new LoaderContext(false,this.loaderInfo.applicationDomain);
ctx.allowCodeImport = true;
Loader(addChild(new Loader())).loadBytes(new Components(),ctx);
```

Comment: i try using 'addChild(new component());' but it leads to a bunch of errors. and if i compile the flex app to use RSL, flash fails to load dependencies, i dont know why.

Comment: I'm not sure what all the possible errors can be, but I can think of at least one instance for a common null object reference: the stage. If your swf tries to access the stage as soon as it initialize, the code would probably work fine when you compile the swf itself, but when you load it and create a new instance it isn't added to the display list yet, so the stage would be null until that happens, in which case I recommend using an event handler for Event.ADDED_TO_STAGE to initialize the stage dependent code in the swf you load. HTH

Answer (score 2):

I think you should use loadBytes of Loader class, similar to described solution here: [how to embed swf file](http://cookbooks.adobe.com/post_How_to_embed_swf_file_containing_ActionScript_code-12871.html)